# Is it possible to read android mobile device RAM content?

Tags: mobile, ram, dynamic-memory-allocation

Is it possible to read android mobile device RAM content.

I am able to see passwords in RAM using HxD editor.
Is it possible to view the password using any tool on device?

Answer (score 1):

Just taking a heap dump of ram with android studio dude.
You take the heap dump and seek the package name you are looking for and probably you can find passwords and whatever is in RAM.